# Read strings and send binary to STM32 via UART

Tags: qt, hex, stm32, uart

I want read and send thousand of rows from PC to STM32 mikrocontroller using UART interface.

Rows looks like:

```
1089,1089,1089,1089
1089,1089,1089,1089
1101,1101,1101,1101
1126,1126,1126,1126
1259,1221,1208,1270
1285,1248,1236,1295
1312,1277,1266,1322
1337,1303,1292,1347
1351,1316,1304,1361
...
```

STM32 should save a binary data first, and then be able to read row after row and set PWM values every 100ms.

1. How can I convert a string to binary/hex using QT Creator (send string via UART is to much bytes)?
2. What is a better way to save a bin amount of rows (up to 20000 rows) on STM32 - arrays? binary file?
3. Should I use an external storage?

Thank you!

Comment: You would be better off transferring ASCII text (or packed BCD) with the punctuation and newlines as separators.  With binary values, you need to define endian order, number of bytes per value, how negative numbers are represented, and how each binary value is delimited.

Comment: Hello, thank you for Answer. Can you tel me how is the fastest UART speed to send data from PC to SMT32F407VG? I choose 115200 Baud, or its possible to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [QString::toInt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt) or [QByteArray::toInt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toInt) functions to convert string or bytearray to integer.
   If you send a row as string, one row will be 16 byte (including LF(0x0A) character). If you send as binary the size of row will decreasing. However I recommend to use one of the standard protocols that using checksum.
2. 3 - Depending on the size of the internal memory and your needs. External memory like EEPROM or FLASH can be used

Comment: Thank you for answer, I think I will try to send UTF-8. Now, I need send this format:
`#000000,1234,1256,1489,1789#
#000100,1356,1289,1478,1589#`

And recieve back:
`#000000,245,245,125,236#
#000100,265,275,112,256#
#Start_audio_record#
#000300,265,275,112,256#
..........
#next_block#
.........
#004500,265,275,112,256#
#stop_audio_recording#`